# Need to update HABTM checkboxes based on a select menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails 3.1 app, I have a Timesheet model. A Timesheet belongs to a Track. A Track has many TimingEyes.

When I create a new Timesheet and select its Track (via a select menu), I need to dynamically display a group of checkboxes for choosing Timing Eyes that were activated that day. At the moment I can display all the timing eyes available in my database, however there are a dozen tracks each with several timing eyes. This is way too much information on the new Timesheet form.

Is there a way I can limit the group of Timing Eyes to the track_id chosen in my select menu? Would there be an advantage to making this a multistep form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi step form wouldn't be a bad thing here and would remove complexity... if you want to stay with a single page form though, this sounds like a great time for some jquery.

Use [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to fire whenever the select box changes value.

When this fires use [.get (ajax)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to render your "checkbox" section html.

So a basic boilerplate would look something like this:

```
$("#trackselect").change(function () {
    $.get('yoururl', function(data) {
       $('#checkboxsection').html(data);
    });
})
```

With this setup you need to define a url/page that outputs the checkboxes html for that particular track. Maybe something like (http://yourdomain.com/tracks/:id/checkboxes).

Hope this helps